# How to remove a directory's path from the enviroment variable PATH permanently?

Tags: 22.04, environment-variables, paths, anaconda, conda

I just removed the miniconda3's folder from home/username/, now i want to remove its path from my $PATH variable permanently.

As you can see below, it's the first one:

> /home/username/miniconda3/bin:/home/username/miniconda3/condabin:/home/username/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.1/bin:/home/username/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current/bin

How can i remove it from my PATH variable?

Comment: Find where it was set, check your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy, as commented by mestia above. You need to find where the addition happens, probably in one of your files `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`, and remove the addition!

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it worked for me. Only have to change the path.

```
PATH=$(REMOVE_PART="--PATH TO REMOVE--" sh -c 'echo ":$PATH:" | sed "s@:$REMOVE_PART:@:@g;s@^:\(.*\):\$@\1@"')
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178822/543146